# The term “URL=Test.com” is not recognized

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I have the following in my test file. I’m trying to use env variables on my scripts then send the value thru commandline.

```
const MYURL = process.env.URL;
console.log(MYURL)
```

In the commandline when I run the following:

```
URL=Test.com npx playwright test
```

I get an error message:

`The term ‘URL=Test.com’ is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet..etc.`

Answer (score 0):

Because you use bash syntax in Powershell. Powershell does not set env variables like `var=value`, so this syntax won't work.

You probably need to read something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1) to figure out the right syntax for Powershell.

Comment: I'm new to Playwright and I'm not familiar with environment variables. I tried $Env:URL ="test.com" and got the same result.